# lsusb outputs "Illegal Instruction" - why?

Tags: usb, libraries

I'm trying to get a 3G USB dongle to work on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Wheezy, using a script called sakis3g.

However, in trying to do this, I keep running into problems: when trying to connect to the USB device, the script prints "Illegal Instruction" and gets no further. I've posted a [question about this on the Raspberry Pi Stack Overflow site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6708/lsusb-command-outputs-illegal-instruction-part-of-making-sakis3g-work), and was given a guide to try to follow (BigCowPi's answer). However, as I said over there, when I try to run `lsusb` (the first thing in that guide), it still outputs "Illegal Instruction" and gets no further.

I've tried reinstalling [usbutils](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/usbutils) and [libsub-1.0-0](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libusb-1.0-0) for armhf, but this hasn't helped the situation.

It might also be worth mentioning that I haven't got access to the internet on it at present, so I've been downloading packages for installation and using dpkg, rather than something simpler like apt-get.

I haven't managed to get an answer from the Raspberry Pi site, so I thought it might be worth asking here instead as it might be a more Linux-related problem anyway.

### Output from strace lsusb

As requested by @Flup, here's the output from `strace`:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop $ strace lsusb -o > lsusblog.log
execve("/usr/bin/lsusb", ["lsusb", "-o"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x914000
uname({sys="Linux", node="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4005a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 44, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x40155000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\10\4\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 3456, SEEK_SET)                = 3456
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1240) = 1240
lseek(3, 2537, SEEK_SET)                = 2537
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=7332, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 35276, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x4022f000
mprotect(0x40230000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x40237000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40237000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x40155000, 44)                  = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37860, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 37860, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x40046000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\f\"\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 37532, SEEK_SET)               = 37532
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1040) = 1040
lseek(3, 37256, SEEK_SET)               = 37256
read(3, "A4\0\0\0aeabi\0\1*\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 53) = 53
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=38572, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 70084, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40122000
mprotect(0x4012b000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x40132000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8) = 0x40132000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0008\33\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 86632, SEEK_SET)               = 86632
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 86300, SEEK_SET)               = 86300
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=87792, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 119072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x4008f000
mprotect(0x400a3000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x400ab000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14) = 0x400ab000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\210y\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1186592, SEEK_SET)             = 1186592
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1360) = 1360
lseek(3, 1186156, SEEK_SET)             = 1186156
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1187952, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1230120, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40238000
mprotect(0x40357000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x4035f000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11f) = 0x4035f000
mmap2(0x40362000, 9512, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40362000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\300\26\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 25312, SEEK_SET)               = 25312
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1320) = 1320
lseek(3, 24924, SEEK_SET)               = 24924
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26632, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 57876, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40063000
mprotect(0x40069000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x40070000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5) = 0x40070000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\274V\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 82712, SEEK_SET)               = 82712
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1400) = 1400
lseek(3, 82308, SEEK_SET)               = 82308
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=116462, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4003c000
mmap2(NULL, 123412, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x400ad000
mprotect(0x400c1000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x400c8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13) = 0x400c8000
mmap2(0x400ca000, 4628, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x400ca000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0`\364\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 130212, SEEK_SET)              = 130212
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 129880, SEEK_SET)              = 129880
read(3, "A2\0\0\0aeabi\0\1(\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 51) = 51
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=131372, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 162704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x400cc000
mprotect(0x400ec000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x400f3000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f) = 0x400f3000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4000a000
set_tls(0x4000a4c0, 0x4000ab98, 0x40045048, 0x4000a4c0, 0x40045048) = 0
mprotect(0x400c8000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x40070000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4035f000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x400ab000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x40132000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x40044000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0x40046000, 37860)               = 0
set_tid_address(0x4000a068)             = 2041
set_robust_list(0x4000a070, 0xc)        = 0
futex(0xbeb6d5e8, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 400c9000) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x400b220c, [], SA_SIGINFO|0x4000000}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x400b20b4, [], SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO|0x4000000}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
--- SIGILL (Illegal instruction) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGILL +++
Illegal instruction
```

### Output from strace sudo lsusb

And just in case it made a difference, I tried sudo too. No `Illegal Instruction`, but no output (such as a list of devices) either.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ strace sudo lsusb
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "lsusb"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x10e4000
fcntl64(0, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(1, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(2, F_GETFD)                     = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
uname({sys="Linux", node="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40001000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 44, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x40102000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\10\4\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 3456, SEEK_SET)                = 3456
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1240) = 1240
lseek(3, 2537, SEEK_SET)                = 2537
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=7332, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 35276, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40160000
mprotect(0x40161000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x40168000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40168000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x40102000, 44)                  = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37860, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 37860, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x4009c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0TM\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 107532, SEEK_SET)              = 107532
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1120) = 1120
lseek(3, 107244, SEEK_SET)              = 107244
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108652, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 142424, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x400eb000
mprotect(0x40105000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x4010c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19) = 0x4010c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\344\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8688, SEEK_SET)                = 8688
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 8356, SEEK_SET)                = 8356
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9848, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 41128, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40085000
mprotect(0x40087000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x4008e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0x4008e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0(\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8652, SEEK_SET)                = 8652
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 8320, SEEK_SET)                = 8320
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9812, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 41136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40090000
mprotect(0x40092000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x40099000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0x40099000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\210y\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1186592, SEEK_SET)             = 1186592
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1360) = 1360
lseek(3, 1186156, SEEK_SET)             = 1186156
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1187952, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1230120, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x40169000
mprotect(0x40288000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0x40290000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11f) = 0x40290000
mmap2(0x40293000, 9512, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40293000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4004c000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4009b000
set_tls(0x4009b4c0, 0x4009bbe8, 0x40084048, 0x4009b4c0, 0x40084048) = 0
mprotect(0x40290000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x40099000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4008e000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4010c000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x26000, 4096, PROT_READ)      = 0
mprotect(0x40083000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0x4009c000, 37860)               = 0
statfs64("/sys/fs/selinux", 88, 0xbef755c8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs64("/selinux", 88, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=931609, f_bfree=555069, f_bavail=507743, f_files=237568, f_ffree=171092, f_fsid={1545102210, 1047066944}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x10e4000
brk(0x1105000)                          = 0x1105000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x400ae000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 281
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x400ae000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1534656, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1534656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x40296000
close(3)                                = 0
geteuid32()                             = 1000
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4000c000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x4000c000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is sudo "..., 54effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?) = 54
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(0)                                = 0
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 0
fcntl64(0, F_GETFD)                     = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
_llseek(0, 0, [0], SEEK_SET)            = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x40265084, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={10, 0}}, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
fcntl64(0, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
read(0, "\10\0\0\0&\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\1\0\0\0002N\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\10\0\0\0\33\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\6\0\0\0!\7\0\0tty2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\7\0\0\0u\7\0\0tty1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\6\0\0\0#\7\0\0tty4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\6\0\0\0\"\7\0\0tty3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\6\0\0\0%\7\0\0tty6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\6\0\0\0$\7\0\0tty5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\6\0\0\0&\7\0\0ttyAMA0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "\7\0\0\0\7\10\0\0pts/0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(0, "", 384)                        = 0
fcntl64(0, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={9, 976098}}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

### tl;dr

What could cause the `lsusb` command to only print `Illegal Instruction` to the console and then exit?

Comment: Can you post the output of `strace lsusb` (or at least the last dozen or so lines)?

Comment: @Flup I'm at work at the minute, but I can try it tonight at home and post back tomorrow. Thanks for replying, by the way - I've been tearing my hair out for ages over this problem...

Comment: @Flup I've added the trace information - have at it!

Comment: I'm not familiar with mips architecture, but this message: "SIGILL (Illegal instruction) @ 0" (note the 0) may simply mean a null pointer dereference.  On x86 this would cause a SIGSEGV.  Also, sudo never ran lsusb: "effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"

Comment: @sendmoreinfo Any thoughts on why a well-used and proven program like lsusb would suddenly be trying to dereference a null pointer, though? I'd assume it's something I've done wrong elsewhere, but I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: No idea.  If in doubt, run it under `gdb` :-)

Comment: @sendmoreinfo And that's the sort of thing a complete linux novice like me needs to know :P I'll try that and have a look.